# Convert data frame to 4d array in R

Tags: r

I have a data-set of patients called fusion which has multiple columns which are in 4 categories, i.e., caseid(n=53), judge(n=3), method(n=5), and technique(n=104). I want to split it into a 4 dimensional array of dimension-lengths 53,3,5,4. Right now this is how the data frame looks:

```
'id'   'judge'    'method'    'technique1'    'technique2'    'technique3' .. 'technique107'

  A      1           M1        1.21           1.4             5.65   
  B      2           M2        45             43              6 23
  C      3           M3        4              31              723
  D      2           M4        55             73              823
  E      1           M5        67             33              423
  F      3           M2        33             93              28
  G      1           M1        5              83              28

  ZZ     1           ..        ..            ..                ..
```

I want the array dimension names to match 'caseid', 'judge' 'method' 'technique' and also, since each case is unique i want the 53 rows to each have row.names = fusion$caseid. Can someone please help? I have been trying plyr, apply, etc.. but as a newbie i havent been successful. Will be happy to elaborate.

Answer (score 3):

We could `melt` the dataset from `wide` to `long` format, specifying the 'id.var' columns, create the `array` using the 'value' column with `dimnames` and `dim` based on the  `unique` values and `length` of `unique` values from the non-numeric columns of 'dM'.

```
library(reshape2)
dM <- melt(d, id.var=c('id', 'judge', 'method'))
l1 <- lapply(dM[1:4], unique)
ar1 <- array(dM$value, dim=lengths(l1), dimnames=l1)
```

#### data

```
d1 <- expand.grid(id= c(LETTERS, paste0(LETTERS, LETTERS), 'AAA'),
     judge=1:3, method=paste0('M', 1:5))
set.seed(24)
d2 <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(nrow(d1)*104), ncol=104, 
      dimnames=list(NULL, paste0('technique', 1:104))))
d <- cbind(d1, d2)
```